# --request-timeout option in kubectl command gives exit code 1

Tags: logging, kubectl

I am trying to run kubectl logs command for on-going logs for a pod. Since the logs for this pod are huge, we are interested in only collecting these logs for first 60 seconds. The way I am achieving is by using --request timeout option as below:

**kubectl -n vdu logs deployment/pod-name -c pod-name -f --request-timeout='60s'**

We are able to collect the logs for 60s, but we get an Exit code 1 upon its completion, which is a problem for us. I am wondering if there is any other way to achieve this with Exit code 0?

Thanks very much!!

Answer (score 0):

Reading from the [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/kubectl/), the request timeout specifies the length of time to wait before giving up on a single server request. Since you provided a timeout value of `60s` the request timed out, which is giving you the status code 1.